# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when using ReactiveForms and NgbModal

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap

I have a reactive form and when the user presses the ESC key in an input i would like to show an "are you sure" modal before the form gets hidden.
As soon as the modal is shown i get the following exception in the console:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has 
changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current 
value: 'ng-untouched: false'.
```

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyw4fp?file=app%2Fmodal-component.ts) that shows the issue (focus input and press ESC)

**Note:** When you focus the input, blur and focus again the issue wont appear as `ng-untouched` wont change again.

Is there any workaround? Whats the recommended way to implement such a functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is because the value of ng-untouched is changed very frequently

Comment: in my case setTimeout didnt solve the problem. I had to set the control as touched before  opening the confirmation modal.
```control.markAsTouched()```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a way to overcome the issue but still having the dirty flag maintained.

ng-untouched is maintained onBlur when FormControl is set to `{updateOn:'change'}` (the default). What you have to do is simply blur the input manually before opening the modal. When the modal is shown it will blur anyway.

[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gyw4fp-zblefo?file=app/modal-component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  test: new FormControl('',{updateOn:'submit'})
})
```

Comment: it works, thanks. Did not know about `updateOn` before. But: to implement the explained functionality i would like to display the modal when the form is dirty, only. As updateOn is set to 'submit' dirty will be false as long as the form is not submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is to `blur` the activeElement before opening the dialog.  Here is an example that displays a modal dialog when `new` is selected.

```js
{
  type: 'select',
  key: 'destination',
  templateOptions: {
    label: 'To Account',
    options: [...accounts],
    required: true,
    disabled: false,
  },
  hooks: {
    onInit: (field) => {
      field.form.get('destination').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        if( value == 'new' ){
            (document.activeElement as any).blur();
            this.modal.open(AddAccountDialogComponent);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the onESC block of code inside setTimeout, which will trigger Angular Change detection using zone.js.

```
onEsc() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the issue of keyup event rather it's an issue of custom modal which you are using. Try to remove the modal and it will work or you need to initialize it first.